# Completion of a sequence space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $F$ be a field with some absolute value $|\cdot|$. Consider the space $X$ of sequences $\mathbf{a} = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots)$ for which $a_i \in F$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and at most finitely many $a_i$ are nonzero. Define on $X$ a norm $$\|\mathbf{a}\| = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |a_i|$$ This norm induces a metric on $X$. I am interested in figuring out what is the completion of $X$ under this metric. I suspect it is exactly the sequences $\mathbf{a} = (a_1, a_2, \cdots)$ for which $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$ is summable. How could I prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the following.

Put

$$\hat X=\{(a_i)\in F^\Bbb N: \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |a_i|<\infty\}.$$

Define on $\hat X$ a norm $$\|\mathbf{a}\|’ = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |a_i|.$$

This norm induces a metric on $\hat X$,  which makes it a complete metric space.

Moreover, $\|\cdot\|’|_X=\|\cdot\|$ and $X$ is a dense subspace of the space $\hat X$. So the space $\hat X$ is a completion of the space $X$.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you!